# Count the occurance of a word in a text file

Tags: c++

I have a text file that I am supposed to open, scan, and count the amount of times a particular word or string occurs in the text file ("#email" to be exact).  I have been able to count the number of words that occurs in the whole text file but not count the number of times a particular word or string occurs.  Can anyone give me any advice?

```
int count = 0;
std::string word;
std::string strg1("#email");
std::ifstream fin;

fin.open(filename + "-inbox.txt", std::ios::in);

while (fin >> word)
{

    if (word == strg1)
    {
        count++;
    }
}

fin.close();
return count;
```

Comment: Do you mean counting how many times each word appears? There's a lot of duplicates for that.

Comment: does this not already do what you want...?

Comment: Unless there is something crazy about your file. I think this already works ... http://ideone.com/G5xmUu

Comment: Try reading the whole file into a string (or read line by line) and then use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: You're right guys, this does work.  I had some other line in there that I took out before posting this. My apologies.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems fine to me (and compier as well). But be aware of the fact, that `istream`'s overloaded `operator>>` for `std::string` reads "words", which is (by means of C++), sequence of chars divided by whitespace. Your example reads such words. So in sentence

> There are many #email words in this sentence (#email is located in here also), but #email, for some reason, is not here.

has only one occurence of `#email` (and one `(#email` and one `#email,`).

Comment: But it is easy to modify the local so that punctuation is treated as space: [How to tokenzie (words) classifying punctuation as space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154217/14065)