# Best way to only retain the words and apostrophe into a string?

Tags: c++, string

Lets say I have something as such:

```
string s;
cout << "Enter a word:";
cin >> s;

//clean s

print(s);
```

If someone enters something like `--sorry` or `what,`, I want to be able to 'clean' the string before passing it into the function which prints out the word. Cleaning a string is making it a word. In this case, a word would be defined as any consecutive strings of letters (also apostrophes can be there, for example `don't` is one word. So getting rid of anything else in there.

I was thinking something like this:

```
string s;
cout << "Enter a word:";
cin >> s;

//clean s
string s2;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] = "'")
       s2[i] = s[i];

print(s2);
```

But this makes my program not work, so I need to figure out another way to do this.

Thank you!

edit:

```
string s;
cout << "Enter a word:";
cin >> s;

//clean s
s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c) || 
c == '\'' || c == '\-' || c == ','; }));

print(s);
```

Edit (latest):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string s;
    cout << "Enter a word:";
    cin >> s;

    //clean s
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c)
    {
        return !isalpha(c) || c == '\'' || c == '-' || c == ',' || c == ';' || c == ':';
    }));

    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: you access `s2` out of range... and you should have 2 indexes

Comment: Is C++11 and [`regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) an option?

Comment: You can set the local to treat everything but characters and apostrophes as space (thus they will be ignored when read with `operator>>`). http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154217/14065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `s2` is default constructed.  That means it has a size of 0.  When you  try to store characters into it with

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] = "'")
       s2[i] = s[i];
```

You are attempting to access memory that doesn't exist.  What you can do is use the `+=` operator of string to add the valid characters of `s1` into `s2` like

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] = "'")
       s2 += s[i];
```

You could also use the erase-remove idiom and just modify `s1` and not even have `s2`.  You could do that like

```
s1.erase(std::remove_if(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
                        [](char ch){ return !(std::isalpha(ch) || ch == '\''); }), 
         s1.end());
```

Comment: if I try to do it without the erase-remove idiot it gives me an error message because `s[i]  = " ' "` doesn't work (a value of type const char* cannot be assigned to an entity of type char). I tried with two equal signs as well and it doesn't work still

Comment: @StacksAndParsing What is the updated code you used?  You should just be able to copy and paste what I wrote.

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Your `c != '-', ','` should be `c != '\''` like I have in my example

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Just take the code I wrote and replace `s1` with `s` and it should work.

Comment: @StacksAndParsing It looks like you are missing the end iterator in the erase call. [This example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d50d1df4eeb73b5f) does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove):

```
s.erase(
    std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return ???; }),
    s.end()
    );
```

Fill in the `???` with the appropriate filter for characters you want to get rid of. Perhaps something like:

```
[](char c){ return !isalpha(c) && c != '\''; }
```

Comment: I tried `s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c) && c != '-', ','; }));` but now it is removing the first character of the string and there are still commas and stuff

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Notice which arguments I am passing to `erase()`.  Also what are you doing with that comma there, that's totally wrong.

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Your filter right now is basically `return true;`

Comment: Like this: `s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {return !isalpha(c) && c != '\'' && c!='-' && c!=','; }));`. I can see the words now but it didn't get rid of the other stuff.